# Verification using Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The exercise asks to verify

$$y(x) = x + \frac{2x^3}{3!} + \frac{24x^5}{5!} + ... = \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

by expanding $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ in Maclaurin's series

I've got the series as $\displaystyle x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} + ...$

but how does that verify $y$ when they don't look the same??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{3!} = \frac{2!}{3!} = \frac13$$

$$\frac{24}{5!}=\frac{4!}{5!}=\frac15$$

Your answer is right, the representation in the book is strange(to me).

It was either to confuse the student, or they approached the problem differently, (I know next to nothing about series, but hey, I only cancelled factorials) and their form arose naturally somehow.

Comment: This has happened to me countless times, more so when I first started learning indefinite integration. The answer keys used to be all jumpled up, even though my answer only differed by writing the constant elsewhere, sometimes it was hard to catch. For instance, $-\arccos$ instead of $\arcsin$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$$
\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right).
$$
Now, you can use [Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) for $\log(1+x)$ and $\log(1-x)$. The rest should be technical matter and I leave it to you.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: The question isn't a derivation for the series, but rather, if his answer his right(which it is!).

Comment: @Sabyasachi Alas!? I didn't see it. Apologize for being silly of this one.

Comment: Happens to all of us.